# Pivot Rows to Columns considerate Column Name and Value Columns SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have next dataset (only use yellows cell). Only considerate, for example get columns iemitidos:
[image]

The next image has the results that I need:
[image]

Comment: please do not use picture to display tables and be your only source of table info, please use plain text or table markdown and include some DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't invent anything smarter (for MS SQL).  Does this work for you?

```
declare
    @t table (f1 varchar (20), dt date, f2 int, f3 int, f4 int)

insert into @t
values
('ACS1', '2021-09-01',1727, 938, 0),
('ACS2', '2021-09-01',1513, 676, 0),
('ACS1', '2021-09-10',1759, 326, 10),
('ACS2', '2021-09-10',1524, 265, 15)

;with cte
as (
select row_number() over (partition by f1 order by (select dt)) rn, * from @t
)
select 
t1.f1, t1.f2, t2.f2, t1.f3, t2.f3, t1.f4, t2.f4 
from cte t1
cross join cte t2
where t1.f1=t2.f1
and t1.f2!=t2.f2
and t1.rn=1
```

OUPTUP:

```
f1      f2      f2      f3   f3     f4  f4
ACS1    1727    1759    938  326    0   10
ACS2    1513    1524    676  265    0   15
```

Comment: I appreciate your help